# How to remove limit parameter from URL in express-paginate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to add paging using express-paginate module. But i am getting limit parameter in url like this: http://example.com:3010/feeds?page=2&limit=10.

But i don't want to use limit in url. How i can remove limit from url?

Below is my pug file code.

```
if paginate.hasPreviousPages || paginate.hasNextPages(pageCount)
.navigation.well-sm#pagination
ul.pager
if paginate.hasPreviousPages
li.previous
a(href=paginate.href(true)).prev
i.fa.fa-arrow-circle-left
|  Previous
if pages
each page in pages
a.btn.btn-default(href=page.url)= page.number
if paginate.hasNextPages(pageCount)
li.next
a(href=paginate.href()).next
| Next&nbsp;
i.fa.fa-arrow-circle-right`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add this by creating a simple middleware function, e.g.

```
const app = express();
const DEFAULT_PAGE_COUNT = 10;

// Intercept all calls and add a default page count.
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (!("limit" in req.query)) {
        req.query.limit = DEFAULT_PAGE_COUNT;
    }
    next();
});
```

And actually, I believe the module supplies this middleware function, e.g.

```
// keep this before all routes that will use pagination
// paginate.middleware(limit, maxLimit)
const paginate = require('express-paginate');

app.use(paginate.middleware(10, 50));
```